# SCP not actually copying files from EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, scp

I'm having an issue copying a file from an EC2 instance.

```
> scp aws:/home/ubuntu/test.test .
AWS shell started
```

This just prints this string which comes from `~/.bashrc` on the instance, but it doesn’t actually copy the file.

And ssh works just fine:

```
> ssh aws
```

EDIT:

Here's the output with the `-vvv`:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <EC2-INSTANCE-ID> (via proxy).
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: proc
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env PYENV_SHELL
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_EXE
debug3: Ignored env _CE_M
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env MOTD_SHOWN
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_CLASS
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env _CE_CONDA
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_PYTHON_EXE
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
debug3: Ignored env PYENV_ROOT
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env _
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f /home/ubuntu/test.test
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
Sink: AWS shell started
AWS shell started
debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 3 len 0
debug2: channel 0: read failed
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 3 efd 7 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 0: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: write failed
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o0 sock -1 wfd 6 efd 7 [write])
debug2: channel 0: send eow
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: output open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 75
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 38
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/113 fd -1/-1/7 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3048, received 2508 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 6448.6, received 5306.1
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Comment: What is `aws`? Some alias?

Comment: Yeah, defined in `.ssh/config`.

Comment: That `AWS shell started` message is a little weird. Does it work if you do _not_ use the Alias?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No.

Comment: If you do _not_ use the alias, does it still show the `AWS shell started` message? That is, you would use `scp -i key.pem ubuntu@1.2.3.4/home/ubuntu/test.test .`